# Последствия некорректных выходов из 1С. Борьба с выходами и последствиями.

Tags: 1с

Добрый день, сообщество.

Мой вопрос больше теоретического характера.
Известно, что после некорректного выхода из системы, пользователь зависает в ней, и его приходится выбрасывать оттуда вручную.  Какие еще последствия могут быть из за некорректных выходов?

У нас, например, 1С со временем начинает загружаться и "думать" дольше. Один из опытных программистов, который разрабатывал нашу конфигурацию, сказал, что подобные тормоза в системе могут возникать из-за постоянного накапливания нек. выходов. Что вы можете сказать по этому поводу? Мне брать палку и бить юзеров по рукам?

**UPD**
1С:Предприятие 8.2 (8.2.15.289)
Бухгалтерия предприятия КОРП, редакция 2.0 (2.0.32.4) 
Размер файла 1Cv8.1CD - 4,6 GB

Comment: Файловая или клиент-серверная схема работы?

Comment: забыл о системе написать) секунду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависание клиентской 1ски подвешивают пользователей и с этим ничего не поделать. Зависла => пользователь висит, по рукам тут бить ни к чему. Надо рубить такие коннекты. [Тут](http://forum.infostart.ru/forum16/topic50242/) люди с переменным успехом борются, но в основном на серверных базах.

Из стандартных решений:

- Провести тестирование и исправление
- Поставить платформу поновее. Последняя 8.2.17.169. И ждать 18-ю и последующие.

ЗЫ Количество [текущих ошибок](http://downloads.v8.1c.ru/content/Platform/8_2_17_169/ErrPlatform_8_2_17_169.htm) впечатляет, в том числе есть и связанные с падениями...

Answer (score 1):

Файловая версия НАМНОГО более чувствительна к некорректным завершениям чем к-с. И замедленее это самое меньшее что вы можете получить. Если некорректный выход произойдёт во время каких-либо регламентных операций, массовых перепроводок и т.д., то ваша база может совсем накрыться - даже ТИИ не поможет - прийдётся chkdbfl вызывать.

И есть одно но - при работе по сети зависшие сеансы могут появиться и при корректном выходе из программы. Это может быть связано с ошибками конфигурации, а может при нестабильной работе сети.

Comment: я так понимаю, лучшее, что я могу сделать, это исправить ошибки и перевести базу на клиент-серверный вариант?

Comment: Тестирование и исправление лучше делать регулярно. Потому что в больших базах ошибки склонны накапливаться.

Ну и конечно, к-с вариант лучше, в особенности на таких больших базах.